# CPU Affinity on the Mac 10.6+ and Xcode 4+

Tags: xcode, macos

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question but here it is anyway.

I remember back in the days with Xcode 3.x, there was a prefPane that once installed, it would allow you to turn on and off of your CPU cores. This was removed in Xcode 4. I was just wondering if there are any utilities in OS X >= 10.6 that will accomplish a similar feat or at least be able to just type a command and assign a process to a CPU core?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the processor pane is still there but needs to be installed.

it should be at /Developer/Extras/PreferencePanes/

Alternatively you can set the processor control in NVRAM but this requires a reboot

as follows

```
     $ sudo nvram boot-args="cpus=1"
```

more details at the docs link

A third option may be the CPUPalete app. If this is on your system you can find it

/Library/Application Support/HWPrefs/CPUPalette.app

Apple's docs are here [Apple CPU control](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1141/_index.html)

Comment: As I've said, the preference pane is not there anymore. Is there a way to set CPU affinity without restarting but short of writing my own little C program?

Comment: i just did a reinstall of xcode 4.0.2 and the pref pane is there on my install . Perhaps you can look inside your xcode installer .